# React Native Firebase: Trying to port to a new firebase project but app shows older values

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, installation, react-native-firebase

I am trying to port my existing RN app from an older firebase project to another one. But when I change the `google-services.json` to a new one pointing to the new Firebase project the references to my older Firebase project still remains.

**Things I've tried**

1. Cleared watchman caches, deleted node_modules, metro cache.
2. Tried deleting the `google-services.json` but even without the file it points to the older project.

*I've deleted the older project but still no avail.*

> What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and then reinstalling the app from the mobile phone?

Comment: I did do it, but I've figured out that it was a cache issue and by deleting the generated files I was able to overcome it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this but deleting the generated values under `android/app/build/generated/res/google-services`. These were holding cache to the previous project.